# How to write an array to file in C

Tags: c, io

I have a 2 dimensional matrix:

```
char clientdata[12][128];
```

What is the best way to write the contents to a file? I need to constantly update this text file so on every write the previous data in the file is cleared.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a human-readable text file?

Comment: Is the data numbers? Strings?  What's going on here?  Can you show an example of the data and what you want the file to look like?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638568/write-2d-array-to-a-file-in-c

Comment: it is strings. example: "4","error_msg","21.1". The file is needed so that I can pull out the data again if needed. So it doesn't have to be human readable in the text file, just when it is pulled out again

Comment: The converse of the problem in [How to read an array saved in binary mode to text file in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599320/how-to-read-array-saved-in-binary-mode-to-text-file-in-c)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Since the size of the data is fixed, one simple way of writing this entire array into a file is using the binary writing mode:

```
FILE *f = fopen("client.data", "wb");
fwrite(clientdata, sizeof(char), sizeof(clientdata), f);
fclose(f);
```

This writes out the whole 2D array at once, writing over the content of the file that has been there previously.

Comment: You use `FILE *ifp = fopen("client.data", "rb"); fread(clientdata, sizeof(char), sizeof(clientdata), ifp);` and add error checking.

Comment: This works across machine types because the data is character data.  If it were `int`, say, then the data would not be portable between big-endian and little-endian machines.

Comment: I am amazed how difficult it was for me to find a good, concise answer to this. Thank you! Thank you, thank you! <3

Answer (score 1):

I would rather add a test to make it robust !
The fclose() is done in either cases otherwise the file system will free the file descriptor

```
int written = 0;
FILE *f = fopen("client.data", "wb");
written = fwrite(clientdata, sizeof(char), sizeof(clientdata), f);
if (written == 0) {
    printf("Error during writing to file !");
}
fclose(f);
```

Answer (score 1):

How incredibly simple this issue turned out to be...
The example given above handle characters, this is how to handle an array of integers...

```
/* define array, counter, and file name, and open the file */
int unsigned n, prime[1000000];
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("/Users/Robert/Prime/Data100","w");
prime[0] = 1;  /* fist prime is One, a given, so set it */
/* do Prime calculation here and store each new prime found in the array */
prime[pn] = n; 
/* when search for primes is complete write the entire array to file */
fwrite(prime,sizeof(prime),1,fp); /* Write to File */

/* To verify data has been properly written to file... */
fread(prime,sizeof(prime),1,fp); /* read the entire file into the array */
printf("Prime extracted from file Data100: %10d \n",prime[78485]); /* verify data written */
/* in this example, the 78,485th prime found, value 999,773. */
```

For anyone else looking for guidance on C programming, this site is excellent...

Refer: [https://overiq.com/c-programming/101/fwrite-function-in-c/

Comment: I know this isn't the most important comment in the world but 1 is **not** a prime number

Comment: RGS...
Correct.
By Definition, A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that cannot be formed by multiplying two smaller natural numbers. 

I just figured I needed to include 1, as the first entry in my array, since it is pivotal to all primes?