# Writing an array of integers into a file using C

Tags: c, arrays, file, integer, storage

I would like to write an array of integers into a file using C. However, I get some gibberish in the file.

The code is about a function that converts a decimal number into binary then stores it into a file.

```
int * decToBinary(int n) //function to transform the decimal numbers to binary
{
    static int binaryNum[16]; // array to store binary number      
    int i = 0; // counter for binary array
    while (n > 0) {
        binaryNum[i] = n % 2; // storing remainder in binary array
        n = n / 2;
        i++;
    }
    return binaryNum;
}

int main()
{  
   FILE *infile;
   int i;
   int *p;
   int decimal= 2000;
   int written = 0;

   infile = fopen("myfile.txt","w");
   p = decToBinary(decimal);
   written = fwrite(p,sizeof(int),sizeof(p),infile) ;

   if (written == 0) {
       printf("Error during writing to file !");
   }
   fclose(infile);
   return 0;

}
```

This is what I get in my file:

[image: This is what I get in my file:]

---

This is what I get when I write a text as a test, it does not have any problem with the text, but it has with the array.

```
char str[] = "test text --------- \n";
infile = fopen("myfile.txt","wb");
p=decToBinary(decimal);
fwrite(str , 1 , sizeof(str) , infile);
written = fwrite(p,sizeof(int),sizeof(p),infile) ;
```

[image]

---

And this is what I get when I make this change:

```
written = fwrite(&p,sizeof(int),sizeof(p),infile) ;
```

[image]

Comment: fwrite writes raw binary. If you want ASCII conversion, use fprintf or similar.

Comment: Seems to me you are asking for the sizeof a pointer in `written = fwrite(p,sizeof(int),sizeof(p),infile)` e.g. `sizeof(p)` - according to the func desc. you should however use the number of elements(or omit them to write the full array).

Comment: You explicitly set size of array to 16. Why?

Comment: @Lundin Unfortunately, there's no `%b` format specifier (yet???), so fprintf won't help out either...

Comment: @purec Obviously because of 32-bit `int` and not caring for negative values. Unfortunately, 0 isn't covered appropriately either.

Comment: @purec some of the integers that I will be using require an array up to 16.

Comment: What content exactly do  you expect in the `myfile.txt` file?

Comment: @Lundin `strtol`: string to long, OP wants inverse, int to str, so needs `itoa(..., 2)`, but @*#$!, oversaw that one, too!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write an array to file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18597685/608639)

Answer (score 2):

First, be aware that there are two interpretations for 'binary':

```
int n = 1012;
fwrite(&n, sizeof(n), 1, file);
```

This writes out the data just as is; as it is represented in form of bits, output is considered "binary" (a binary file).

Your question and the code you provided, though, rather imply that you actually want to have a file containing the numbers in binary *text* format, i. e. 7 being represented by string `"111"`.

Then first, be aware that 0 and 1 do not represent the characters `'0'` and `'1'` in most, if not all, encodings. Assuming [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) or compatible, `'0'` is represented by value 48, `'1'` by value 49. As C standard requires digits [0..9] being consecutive characters (this does not apply for any other characters!), you can safely do:

```
binaryNum[i] = '0' + n % 2;
```

Be aware that, as you want strings, you chose the bad data type, you need a character array:

```
static char binaryNum[X];
```

`X`??? We need to talk about required size!

If we create strings, we need to null-terminate them. So we need place for the terminating 0-character (really value 0, not 48 for character `'0'`), so we need at least one character more.

Currently, due to the comparison `n > 0`, you consider negative values as equal to 0. Do you really intend this? If so, you might consider `unsigned int` as data type, otherwise, leave some comment, then I'll cover handling negative values later on.

With restriction to positive values, `16 + 1` as size is fine, assuming `int` has 32 bit *on your system*! However, C standard allows int to be smaller or larger as well. If you want to be portable, use `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) / 2` (`CHAR_BIT` is defined in `<limits.h>`; drop division by 2 if you switch to unsigned int).

There is one special case not covered: integer value `0` won't enter the loop at all, thus you'd end up with an empty string, so catch this case separately:

```
if(n == 0)
{
    binaryNum[i++] = '0';
}
else
{
    while (n > 0) { /.../ }
}
// now the important part:
// terminate the string!
binaryNum[i] = 0;
```

Now you can simply do (assuming you changed `p` to `char*`):

```
written = fprintf(file, "%s\n", p);
//                         ^^ only if you want to have each number on separate line
//                          you can replace with space or drop it entirely, if desired
```

Be aware that the algorithm, as is, prints out least significant bits first! You might want to have it inverse, then you'd either yet have to revert the string *or* (which I would prefer) start with writing the terminating 0 to the end and then fill up the digits one by one towards front - returning a pointer to the last digit (the most significant one) written instead of always the start of the buffer.

One word about your original version:

```
written = fwrite(p, sizeof(int), sizeof(p), infile);
```

`sizeof(p)` gives you the size of a pointer; this one is system dependent, but will always be the same on the same system, most likely 8 on yours (if modern 64-bit hardware), possibly 4 (on typical 32-bit CPU), other values on less common systems are possible as well. You'd need to return the number of characters printed separately (and no, `sizeof(binaryNum)` won't be suitable as it always returns 17, assuming 32-bit int and all changes shown above applied).

Comment: 1) yes, I want "want to have a file containing the numbers in binary text format"
2) I don't want to consider the negative values.

Comment: **CHAR_BIT** defines the number of bits in a byte (source: [link] (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/limits_h.htm) ),  however, the integers that I would like to convert into binary text format can go upto 2 bytes.

Comment: @Lavender `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned int)` -> 8*4 -> 32 (for unsigned) or devide by 2 for signed - as in the answer...

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
...
int main()
{
  int decimal = 2000;    
  int *p = decToBinary(decimal);

  for (int i = 0; i< 16; i++)
  {
    printf("%d", p[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The output goes to the terminal instead into a file.

For writing into a file use `fopen` as in your code, and use `fprintf` instead of `printf`.

Concerning the `decToBinary` there is still room for improvement, especially you could transform the number directly into an array of `char` containing only chars `0` and `1` using the `<<` and `&` operators.

Comment: thank you for the insight about the decRoBinary, do you mean something like this: http://www.c4learn.com/c-programs/decimal-to-binary-using-bitwise-and.html  ?

Comment: @Lavender yes exactly